# Sticky MsgBox - doesn't close

Tags: windows-ce, msgbox

The Message Box called here is not closing upon clicking "OK". Keeps popping up until I kill the task via Task Manager.
The runtime environment is WinCE 6.0.

```vb
Private Sub frmPAConsole_Activated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Activated

    strConfigFileName = "\Program Files\Alarm System\PASystem_AudioFilesAllocation.txt"

    If Not IO.File.Exists(strConfigFileName) Then
        MsgBox("Configuration file doesn't exist: \Program Files\Alarm System\PASystem_AudioFilesAllocation.txt")
        Me.Close()
    End If

    Call LabelStopButton()
    Call ReadConfigFile(strConfigFileName)
    Call PopulateButtonsDescription()

End Sub
```

I tested a message box when just clicking a button - no problem. Also, the device Windows messages are closing normally.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This seems like some sort of a bug.
Even when implementing the Error Message using a new dialog form - the stickiness of the message persisted ONLY for the IO.file.open error (regardless of whether it was raised by error handling or checked if file.exist).

The only workaround I managed to do is instead of having error messages pop up in new windows, I implemented a textbox on the main form itself, on the bottom, for error messages, and I control its text and visibility.

Thank you all for reading and thinking about this issue.